# Emacs - override indentation

Tags: c++, emacs, namespaces, indentation

I have a multiply nested namespace:

```
namespace first {namespace second {namespace third {
              // emacs indents three times
    // I want to intend here
} } }
```

so emacs indents to the third position.  However I just want a single indentation.
Is it possible to accomplish this effect simply?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use an an absolute indentation column inside namespace:

```
(defconst my-cc-style
  '("gnu"
    (c-offsets-alist . ((innamespace . [4])))))

(c-add-style "my-cc-style" my-cc-style)
```

Then use **c-set-style** to use your own style.

Note that this only works in **c++-mode**, c-mode doesn't know 'innamespace'.

Comment: It works in c++-mode, but not works in c++-ts-mode which appears from Emacs29.  Is there couterpart of c-set-style for c++-mode?

Answer (score 20):

With c++-mode in Emacs 23, I had to do like this:

```
(defun my-c-setup ()
   (c-set-offset 'innamespace [4]))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c-setup)
```

To disable the indentation in namespaces altogether, change [4] to 0.

Comment: This worked for me in Emacs 24.5.1 (with `innamespace [0]`), while the accepted answer did not.

Comment: Much better solution than the accepted one, which requires you to mess with the actual style you are using (and doesn't tell you how).   The accepted answer didn't work for me, this does.

Answer (score 4):

OK so this seems to work in both emacs 21 and 22 at least:

```
(defun followed-by (cases)
  (cond ((null cases) nil)
        ((assq (car cases) 
               (cdr (memq c-syntactic-element c-syntactic-context))) t)
        (t (followed-by (cdr cases)))))

(c-add-style  "foo"      
              `(( other . personalizations )
        (c-offsets-alist
         ( more . stuff )
         (innamespace
          . (lambda (x) 
          (if (followed-by 
               '(innamespace namespace-close)) 0 '+))))))
```

(The first solution doesn't support constructs like

```
namespace X { namespace Y {
    class A;
    namespace Z {
        class B;
    }
}}
```

)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to input a literal tab, rather than changing emacs' indentation scheme, `C-q TAB` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think emacs has a separate style for a namespace inside another namespace. If you go to the inner line and do C-c, C-o, you can change the topmost-intro style, and if you run `customize-variable c-offsets-alist` you can edit all the different indentation options emacs has, but one doesn't exist for your specific use case. You would need to write it manually in elisp

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, inherit from cc-mode and replace the name space indenting to 0, aka, disable  it's indent.

```
(defconst my-cc-style
  '("cc-mode"
    (c-offsets-alist . ((innamespace . [0])))))

(c-add-style "my-cc-mode" my-cc-style)
```

Comment: Couple of questions: how do you ensure that my-cc-mode is based on your previous choice of C style, and how do you activate it?

Comment: Activate it by this hook:  (add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
(lambda ()
(c-set-style "my-cc-style")
))

Comment: is there a way to base a style off an existing style? I want my style to be like bsd but without namespace indentation