# Suppress c++ namespace indentation in emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emacs - override indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619853/emacs-override-indentation)

What I want is for emacs to not indent the code inside a namespace

```
namespace a_namespace{

// no indentation
int namespace_global_variable;


// no indentation
class Class {
    // comment
    Class();
    //...
};

// and so on


}
```

When I tried modifying the `innamespace` variable, or using `C-c C-o` to change the indentation at the point of interest, I do not get the desired effect (in fact the latter killed off all of the indentation inside of functions).

My indentation configuration looks like this (copied from the Google emacs configuration):

```
(c-offsets-alist . ((arglist-intro vista-c-lineup-expression-plus-4)
                    (func-decl-cont . ++)
                    (member-init-intro . +)
                    (inher-intro . ++)
                    (comment-intro . 0)
                    (arglist-close . c-lineup-arglist)
                    (topmost-intro . 0)
                    (block-open . 0)
                    (inline-open . 0)
                    (substatement-open . 0)
                    (statement-cont
                     .
                     (,(when (fboundp 'c-no-indent-after-java-annotations)
                         'c-no-indent-after-java-annotations)
                      ,(when (fboundp 'c-lineup-assignments)
                         'c-lineup-assignments)
                      ++))
                    (label . /)
                    (case-label . +)
                    (statement-case-open . +)
                    (statement-case-intro . +) ; case w/o {
                    (access-label . /)
                    (innamespace . -))))
```

Comment: Seems the same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619853/emacs-override-indentation).

Comment: That solution does not work for me (might be user error though).

Comment: This is not a strict duplicate, because the other question asks for _some_ indentation wheras this asks for _none_.   It is possible that the solution for _none_ would be better than the solution for "some with the amount set to zero".

Comment: Just do `(c-set-offset 'innamespace '0)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```lisp
(defconst my-cc-style
  '("cc-mode"
    (c-offsets-alist . ((innamespace . [0])))))

(c-add-style "my-cc-mode" my-cc-style)
```

From [Jason Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043032/jason-zhang)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619853/emacs-override-indentation). Works here.

Comment: Simply replacing the `-` with `[0]` in my existing `c-offsets-alist` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Now it seems to work -- I'm not 100% sure of what it takes for emacs to re-read its init file.

Comment: Somehow this didn't work for me, even after restarting Emacs. `(c-set-offset 'innamespace 0)` worked though (taken from http://brrian.tumblr.com/post/9018043954/emacs-fu-dont-indent-inside-of-c-namespaces)

Comment: Note that the answer that this is copied from states *"Then use c-set-style to use your own style."*   Kinda important missing piece of information here?

Comment: This is old, but for emacs to 're-read its init file': <M>-x eval-buffer (while visiting .emacs or whatever you name it)

Comment: After defining a new style or updating an existing one, you can use `c-set-style` when visiting a buffer with your code. It asks for the desired style. Just select the one you have modified and you should notice the effect of your style changes.